# Drop an item when borders touches the drop area

Tags: drag-and-drop, react-dnd

Any ideas, paths, on how to make react-dnd to drop the item once its borders enters the drop area, Instead of the mouser pointer entering the drop area?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe calculate the position of the dragged element and  if it overlaps with the drop area then programatically trigger the hover/drop state.

Comment: I thought about calculating the dragged element but I am not sure it's possible to pragmatically trigger the hover/drop state.

Comment: try using .dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover', { 'bubbles': true })); or .dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseenter', { 'bubbles': true })); to trigger it

Comment: It won't work on react-dnd because it uses redux actions to dispatch those events.

Comment: I think the solution is to create another backend not based on native drag and drop.